# Colour transition effect on browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a basic task where you hover over a link and it transition into a colour and visa-versa. The problem I am having is that **whenever I change the size of the browser, the text affected responds a lot slower**. I added a media query where it changes the percentage of the font depending on the browser size so I am assuming this has something to do with it. I created a jsfiddle to show you the problem. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mexicanbandit/vbc25Ly2/

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

/* Medium screens ($mediumscreens) */
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  /* line 26, ../sass/screen.scss */
  html {
    font-size: 112%;
  }
}
/* Large screens ($largescreens) */
@media (min-width: 64rem) {
  /* line 33, ../sass/screen.scss */
  html {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce your problem. By "text affeected responds a lot slower", are you referring to the transition duration? Is the transition duration extended, or is it simply lagging? You have to be a bit more detailed in describing your issue.

Comment: The transition itself is fine but when I change the browser viewport size, the font size changes a lot slower but this only happens when I have the transition element on.

Comment: That is because you are transiting **all** properties with a duration of 1s: `transition: all 1s ease`. You can transition the `font-size` property separately then: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/vbc25Ly2/1/

Comment: Yeah that worked :) Instead of using  `transition: all 1s ease, font-size .5s ease;`, I used `transition: color 1s ease;` Now the viewport doesn't affect the text size when it's changed